Optimal SAS HBA for ESXi 8.0 small business server?
Trying to find SAS HBA for small business server setup, used LSI SAS2308 based cards before with ESXi 6/7, but now I have to deal with the lack of support. HBA is working, but tools are outdated and there is lack of management layer (no SMIS provider) for VMware 7/8.
So, what are the HBAs who are cheap enough, supported by ESXi 8.0, have ESXi 8 tools and have SMIS provider to be monitored from ESXi?

An LSI 3008-based card, such as the Dell PERC H330 - $13.99

Per the VMware I/O guide (and, anecdotally, Reddit), the Cisco and Dell variants of LSI's 3008-based cards are supported in ESXi 8.0. These are available on the cheap. I haven't been able to validate SMIS support, but I'd assume that the normal LSI SMIS provider should work just fine since it's a supported card.
